# jQuery gallery using .attr() method and event.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

I have been attempting to create a dynamic jQuery image gallery that does not require the user to be taken to a new destination when they click a link. It can be found here - http://the-session.co.uk/JSgallery/

I have created the `showPic` function which takes 2 arguments - the event object and an element node object (a specific  element that is clicked on with a class of `link)` . The `source` variable uses the `.attr()` method and acts as a "getter" to get the `src` attribute of the element node passed to the `showPic` function.

I have then stored the `<img id="placeholder">` in a variable called `gallery`. The idea was then to set the `src` attribute of `gallery` to the `src` from the `source` variable.

I have then used `event.preventDefault();` so that the  the default action of the event will not be triggered. However the  `elements` are still taking the user to a new destination which is not desired.

The final step was to select `.link` (the `<a>` elements) and then use the `.on` method so that when a user clicks an anonymous function is invoked. The `showPic` function is then called and it is passed the specific  element that was clicked on using `$(this)`.

Currently the code is not working and I do not understand why. Any suggestions?

```
function showPic (event, el) {
    var source = el.attr('source'); // getter
    var gallery = $('#placeholder'); // <img id="placeholder">
    gallery.attr('src', source); // setter
    event.preventDefault();
}

$('.link').on('click', function() {  
        showPic($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the event as well, when inside a function like that :

```
function showPic (event, el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#placeholder').attr('src', el.attr('source'));
}

$('.link').on('click', function(event) {  
    showPic(event, $(this));
});
```

On the other hand if you reference the function directly the event will be passed, and you can use event.target to get the clicked element, if that is the same as the bound element:

```
function showPic (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#placeholder').attr('src', $(event.target).attr('source'));
}

$('.link').on('click', showPic);
```

Answer (score 0):

u missed the first parameter,,

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {  
    showPic(e,$(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your showPic function takes two arguments event and el

But you are only passing the element to showPic and in showPic this element is stored in the event argument.

Update your code to the following:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {  
        showPic(event, $(this));
});
```